# blow up and derived category

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider the blowup $X$ of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a single point $p$. Then, Orlov showed that there is a semiorthogonal decomposition $D^b(X)=\langle e,O_X,O_X(1),O_X(2)\rangle$, where $O_X(i)$ is the pullback of $O_{\mathbb{P}^2}(i)$, and $e$ can be taken to be $i_*O_E(-1)$, where $i:E\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion of the exceptional divisor. The objects $e,O_X(i)$ are in fact all exceptional, so their direct sum should be a tilting object for $D^b(X)$.

But I dont see why for example $Ext^k(e,\mathcal{O}_X(i))=0$, for $k>0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

By Grothendieck duality, $$\mathrm{R}\mathcal{H}om(i_*\mathcal{O}_E(-1),\mathcal{O}_X(i))\cong i_*\mathrm{R}\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{O}_E(-1),i^*\mathcal{O}_X(i))\otimes   \mathcal{O}_E(-1)[-1])\cong i_*\mathcal{O}_E[-1]\ ,$$thus $\mathrm{Ext}^p(i_*\mathcal{O}_E(-1),\mathcal{O}_X(i))=H^{p-1} (E,\mathcal{O}_E)=k\ $ if $\ p=1$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Ok. You take the duality $Rf_*R\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{F},Lf^*(\mathcal{G})\otimes \omega_f[dim(f)])\simeq R\mathcal{H}om(Rf_*\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$. I do not see why $\omega_f[dim(f)]$ is the same as $\mathcal{O}_E(-1)$.

Comment: I think $\omega_i[dim(i)]$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_E(-1)[-1]$.

Comment: You are right. So in fact $\mathrm{Ext}^1(i_*\mathcal{O}_E(-1), \mathcal{O}_X(i))=k$. Why do you believe it is 0? I didn't understand the argument.